# Activation context generation failed for "C:\php\php-cgi.exe". Dependent Assembly

Tags: php, iis-7, windows-server-core

Greeting,
I have Windows Server 2008 Server Core. I want to configure this server to host php websites using IIS 7.

I installed and configured IIS7 to run php using the steps in this website:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/philpenn/deploying-iis-7-5-fastcgi-php-on-server-core)

Now I’m facing a problem that when I request my php website I would get  this error.

Server Error

500 - Internal server error.

There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

I check the even log and I found these details too:

Activation context generation failed for "C:\php\php-cgi.exe". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

I search about this error and I found a solution for it but which is to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86). I installed but still I’m getting same error.

Please help me to solve this problem and let me know if you want to know more info about my issue.

Comment: For what it is worth, installing the VC++ 2008 x86 runtime solved it for me.